# How can I write this "email" in Japanese?

Tags: translation, email

I am writing a science fiction work, and, at some point, the main character writes an email to a very respected scientist in Japan. I was considering writing the email itself in Japanese, if that may be possible...

"Dear Mr. Maskawa,

My name is Alex, and I am a student of biology, but with a lot of interest in physics.

I am contacting you because I would like to ask you a question about your views on the multiverse hypothesis. I have read that you have a positive view towards string theory, since, for example, you once said that superstring theory could possibly create a new kind of physics.

As you probably know, string theory is very related to the hypothesis of the existence of multiple universes. I was wondering what were your thoughts on this (in case you have any):

Do you think that it is possible that multiple universes exist?

If yes, do you consider that these universes could vary in their most fundamental laws of physics? Do you consider that there are many universes, each one with different fundamental laws of physics (like different laws of quantum mechanics, or different laws of thermodynamics, or different laws of conservation of energy and matter...etc)?

Thank you in advance for your answer"

Comment: Aside from the fact that we don't do translations, what are you expecting to happen?  If you email him in Japanese, he'll probably respond in Japanese.  Then what?

Comment: "**Mr.** Maskawa" -- So the "very respected scientist in Japan" doesn't even have a doctor's degree?

Comment: @istrasci I don't think they expect a response... After all, this is all part of a piece of fiction.

Comment: Oops, somehow I missed that it was the character writing the email.  Somehow my eyes only saw "I am writing...a respected scientist in Japan."  @vengaq, sorry for being a jerk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: so I just realized that this place don't do translation. I won't be deleteing my answer but I won't be answering further questions.

"親愛なるMaskawaさんへ(since maskawa is not proper Japanese name; Masakawa or Masukawa possibly?)

私の名前はアレックスです。私は生物学を専攻していて、物理学にも興味を持っています。

多元宇宙論に関するあなたの見解をお聞きしたいと思い、連絡させていただきました。
あなたはひも理論に対して肯定的な見解をお持ちのようですね。例えば、あなたは超ひも理論は新しい物理学を生み出す可能性があるとおっしゃっていました。

ご存知かとは思いますが、超ひも理論は、多元宇宙の存在という仮説と非常に関係があります。このことについて、先生はどのようにお考えでしょうか（もしあれば）。

複数の宇宙が存在することは可能だと思いますか？

もし、複数の宇宙が存在する事が可能だと思われる場合、それらの宇宙は物理学の最も基本的な法則に違いがあると思いますか？
物理学の基本的な法則（量子力学の法則、熱力学の法則、エネルギーと物質の保存の法則...など）が異なる多くの宇宙が存在すると考えますか？

回答をお待ちしております。"

I’m not good at physics/space-thingy(?), so some of my translation could be wrong.

Comment: `Maskawaさんへ` -- 「さん」よりも「先生」のほうがいいのではないでしょうか。  `あなたの見解... あなたは...` -- 「あなた」よりも「先生」のほうがいいのでは。

Comment: 確かに仰るとおりですね、序文は先生のほうがいいと思います。途中はどちらでもいいと思います（ここは結構個人の好みが分かれるポイントだと思います）。